# ERROR "The specified field could refer to more than one table in the FROM clause"

Tags: sql, alias, ms-access-2010

I'm using Access 2010.

My error seems to be a result of the aliasing.

The solutions I've read specify that a different alias should be used at every level (which I've done) and that Access likes lots of SELECT * (so I added those, too) but it hasn't resolved my issue.

I'm getting an error on ServiceZipSpec.Service_Product. Any pointers? Thanks!

```
SELECT DISTINCT ServiceZipSpec.Service_Product, ServiceZipSpec.Specificity, Service_Availability.Available, Service_Availability.Zip_Code, Service_Availability.State
    FROM 
    ( SELECT * FROM 
       ( SELECT * FROM Service_Availability AS C_Avail1
         INNER JOIN 
            (
              SELECT C_Avail2.Service_Product, MAX(C_Avail2.Specificity) AS Spec
              FROM Service_Availability AS C_Avail2
              WHERE (C_Avail2.State = "TX" OR C_Avail2.State = "CW")
              GROUP BY C_Avail2.Service_Product 
            ) MaxSpec
         ON C_Avail1.Service_Product = MaxSpec.Service_Product
             AND C_Avail1.Specificity = MaxSpec.Spec
       ) Service_Spec
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_ZipCodes ON Service_Spec.State = TABLE_ZipCodes.State
    ) ServiceZipSpec

    WHERE ServiceZipSpec.Available = TRUE AND (ServiceZipSpec.State = "TX" OR ServiceZipSpec.State = "CW")
    ;
```

Comment: Do you have a copy of MS Access? If so, why not try the query design window? Some of your ideas are not correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The source of your problem is that you are using `SELECT *` when joining tables that have similarly named columns.  Try limiting to `SELECT table_name.*`, or simply pick out the columns you need.

For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ServiceZipSpec.Service_Product, ServiceZipSpec.Specificity, Service_Availability.Available, Service_Availability.Zip_Code, Service_Availability.State
  FROM 
    ( SELECT Service_Spec.*, TABLE_ZipCodes.Zip_Code FROM 
       ( SELECT C_Avail1.* FROM Service_Availability AS C_Avail1
...
```

Comment: Thanks! I selected your answer for both the solution and the use of table_name.* - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to `SELECT colName1, colname2` instead of the `SELECT *`, you are getting a conflict in your subqueries. Also your outer select list will be from the table with the alias `ServiceZipSpec`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ServiceZipSpec.Service_Product, 
    ServiceZipSpec.Specificity, 
    ServiceZipSpec.Available, 
    ServiceZipSpec.Zip_Code, 
    ServiceZipSpec.State
FROM 
( 
    SELECT colName1, colname2, etc -- name your columns here
    FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT colName1, colname2, etc -- name your columns here
        FROM Service_Availability AS C_Avail1
        INNER JOIN 
        (
          SELECT C_Avail2.Service_Product, MAX(C_Avail2.Specificity) AS Spec
          FROM Service_Availability AS C_Avail2
          WHERE (C_Avail2.State = "TX" OR C_Avail2.State = "CW")
          GROUP BY C_Avail2.Service_Product 
        ) MaxSpec
        ON C_Avail1.Service_Product = MaxSpec.Service_Product
            AND C_Avail1.Specificity = MaxSpec.Spec
   ) Service_Spec
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_ZipCodes 
        ON Service_Spec.State = TABLE_ZipCodes.State
) ServiceZipSpec
WHERE ServiceZipSpec.Available = TRUE 
    AND (ServiceZipSpec.State = "TX" OR ServiceZipSpec.State = "CW");
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! You and PinnyM had the same solution, at the same time, so I struggled with which answer to select. Pinny also used the wildcard for the fields within an alias, e.g. Service_Spec.*, so I ultimately went with his. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The specified field reference could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement. In the following example, the OrderID field exists in both the Orders and Order Details tables:

```
SELECT OrderID 
FROM Orders, [Order Details];
```

Because the statement does not specify which table OrderID belongs to, it produces this error. To complete this operation, fully qualify the field reference by adding a table name. For example:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID 
FROM Orders, [Order Details];
```